# mvc 4 project how to have permissions to get facebook user email after log in using facebook sdk

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, facebook-graph-api, asp.net-membership

i have mvc4 project with facebook login
i want to add the user email to the user profile table
this is my AuthConfig code

```
     OAuthWebSecurity.RegisterFacebookClient(
                appId: "8919945667880789",
                appSecret: "ce8e0b218047693308cb71");
```

and this is my ExternalLoginCallback code

```
   [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)
        {
            AuthenticationResult result = OAuthWebSecurity.VerifyAuthentication(Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl }));
            if (!result.IsSuccessful)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("ExternalLoginFailure");
            }

            if (OAuthWebSecurity.Login(result.Provider, result.ProviderUserId, createPersistentCookie: false))
            {
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }

            if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                // If the current user is logged in add the new account
                OAuthWebSecurity.CreateOrUpdateAccount(result.Provider, result.ProviderUserId, User.Identity.Name);
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }
            else
            {
                // User is new, ask for their desired membership name
                // User is new, ask for their desired membership name
                string loginData = OAuthWebSecurity.SerializeProviderUserId(result.Provider, result.ProviderUserId);
                ViewBag.ProviderDisplayName = OAuthWebSecurity.GetOAuthClientData(result.Provider).DisplayName;
                ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
                var client = new **FacebookClient(result.ExtraData["accesstoken"]);
                dynamic me = client.Get("me");
                string UserEmail = me.email; 
                var model = new RegisterExternalLoginModel { UserName = result.UserName, Email = UserEmail, ExternalLoginData = loginData };


                return View("ExternalLoginConfirmation", model);
            }

        }
```

but when i debug I found the **UserEmail = me.email = null**
what i have to do to get the user email from the facebook ???
thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  var fb = new FacebookClient(result.ExtraData["accesstoken"]);
                    dynamic myInfo = fb.Get("/me?fields=email"); // specify the email field
                   var UserEmail = myInfo.email;
```

that is ok but but your  code between if statment

```
if(OAuthWebSecurity.GetOAuthClientData(result.Provider).DisplayName;== "facebook"){
code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

all what i did that i edit my ExternalLoginCallback  code to be like that

```
public ActionResult ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)
        {
            AuthenticationResult result = OAuthWebSecurity.VerifyAuthentication(Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl }));
            if (!result.IsSuccessful)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("ExternalLoginFailure");
            }

            if (OAuthWebSecurity.Login(result.Provider, result.ProviderUserId, createPersistentCookie: false))
            {
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }

            if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                // If the current user is logged in add the new account
                OAuthWebSecurity.CreateOrUpdateAccount(result.Provider, result.ProviderUserId, User.Identity.Name);
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }
            else
            {
                // User is new, ask for their desired membership name
                // User is new, ask for their desired membership name
                string loginData = OAuthWebSecurity.SerializeProviderUserId(result.Provider, result.ProviderUserId);
                ViewBag.ProviderDisplayName = OAuthWebSecurity.GetOAuthClientData(result.Provider).DisplayName;
                ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;



                var fb = new FacebookClient(result.ExtraData["accesstoken"]);
                dynamic myInfo = fb.Get("/me?fields=email"); // specify the email field
               var UserEmail = myInfo.email;



                //var client = new FacebookClient(result.ExtraData["accesstoken"]);
                //dynamic me = client.Get("me");
                //string UserEmail = me.email;
               var model = new RegisterExternalLoginModel { UserName = result.UserName, Email = UserEmail, ExternalLoginData = loginData };


                return View("ExternalLoginConfirmation", model);
            }

        }
```

this is the code to get the user email

```
  var fb = new FacebookClient(result.ExtraData["accesstoken"]);
                    dynamic myInfo = fb.Get("/me?fields=email"); // specify the email field
                   var UserEmail = myInfo.email;
```

thank you